# AWS S3 client side encryption using KMS - Region being ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the recently release KMS service with Amazon and I'm getting an issue with the Region being ignored when passed into the `AmazonS3EncryptionClient`.

```java
AmazonS3EncryptionClient s3 = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(credentials,
new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(keyId))
.withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));
```

The error message coming back indicates that the key can't be found in the region `US-East-1` despite actively setting it to `EU-West-1`

The error message is

```
 com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.NotFoundException: 
   Key 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:account#:key/mykeyname' does not exist (Service: AWSKMS; 
   Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotFoundException; 
   Request ID: 8fb90ad0-7644-11e4-bf12-0b5a59268629)
```

I can't find any documentation to suggest this is a specific bug in the API, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the comments/suggestions at the bottom of this thread:

http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx19OLB7M3D6DS8/S3-Encryption-with-AWS-Key-Management-Service

Looks like there was a release to address this issue with the addition of a new parameter.

i.e:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain(),
                new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(customerMasterKeyId),
                new CryptoConfiguration().withKmsRegion(Regions.fromName("us-west-2")));
```

Comment: what a nonsense this API is.  Regions.fromName() gives me back what? withAwsKmsRegion method doesn't even take this argument.

So much headache with AWS API all the time..

got finally something like this:
.withCryptoConfiguration(new CryptoConfiguration(CryptoMode.EncryptionOnly).withAwsKmsRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(clientRegion))))